# How to access the child element

Tags: javascript, salesforce-lightning

I have been trying a lot to focus the lightning-input. But I am not getting how to focus the childElement.

[image: In this Image how to get class which is marked in blue color]

The element which I would like to focus is child Element of parentIn. But when I tried to getElementByclassname I am getting undefined , thinking it cant be accessed like that.

How to access the class which is pointed  in the image using JS. I tried but getting undefined

Here is how I tried.

```
let taggingModal = document.getElementById('globalTaggerId').children;
```

I am not getting how to move further. Please help me to get through this.

Comment: you can't focus a div, unless you give it a tabindex attribute. Also you write you want to focus the input, so where is the input you want to focus?

Comment: lightning-input is the child of parentIn which i need to focus

Comment: But `<lightning-input>` is only a container for the input field. See at the documentation at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input and check the DOM in dev-tools. And then you can try `document.querySelector('.parentIn input').focus()`.

Comment: You need to focus the lightning-input or is there a normal `<input>` inside the lightning-input?

Comment: It should be input. But dont know how to access it.

Comment: In LWC I use  this.template.querySelector('lightning-input').focus();
but need to do in VF page

Comment: @RWAM Getting undefined

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
let taggingModal = document.getElementById('globalTaggerId');
taggingModal.getElementsByClassName("parentIn")[0].focus();
```